# Best practice to store HTML in DB

Tags: html, database-design, architecture

I'm developing a companies catalog, where description is kept in HTML format.

Should I store both HTML and text version of description?

Will it impact on full text search, that will be implemented later?

Of course, I can just strip HTML tags in rendering.

What is a best practice for this?

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this is a valid question. I'd store both the plain text description and the formatted HTML description. With HTML only, `<p>This is a <font color="red">great</font> shirt!</p>` you'd have to make sure somehow not to find this description when the user searches for `red` and `shirt`, because `red` is not part of the description.

Answer (score 1):

You could of course consider doing it the other way around. Store fields in the database, then use a HTML template to insert the fields in the required place. Then your data is not duplicated and you can potentially have multiple html  templates for the same underlying data.

Alternatively, you could store your fields in a single db field in some structured format (e.g. XML), and then transform that into html. (e.g. XSL). Note: some dbs can understand XML natively, if your db doesnt support this then you can store individual fields, generate XML from them, then apply XSL to get your html.